# Reverse SSH Tunnel - ssh_exchange_identification

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I am trying to setup a reverse SSH tunnel from server1 that is running behind a NAT (Consumer Fritzbox) to server2 that is reachable from outside.

Therefore i use the following command that is added to the /etc/rc.local of server1.

```
autossh -i /home/user/.ssh/passwordless_id_rsa -f -N -R 10001:localhost:22 user@server2
```

netstat delivers something like

```
tcp        0      0 server1.fritz.box:60805    server2:ssh          ESTABLISHED
```

But whenever i try to access server1 via server2 i get the following message

```
$ ssh -p 10001 localhost
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Strangely, the command works perfectly if run manually after the system is booted. So i assume it may be related to the startup of sshd?

Has anyone experienced this and can help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can someone please move this to a comment? I'm limited by reputation rules. TIA.

When you run `telnet localhost 22` on server1, does it work? Could be a IPv4 vs IPv6 situation, in which case, try using 127.0.0.1 instead.

Does the `-v` option provide more info? Is there anything in the sshd logs on server1?